# Stripe Session Getting Customer Name

Tags: stripe-payments

I would also like to retrieve the name of the person who paid.  How can I get the name value from the stripe session? I have tried this:

```
const sessions = await stripe.checkout.sessions.list({
    limit: 1,
  });
console.log(sessions.data[0].customer)
const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(sessions.data[0].customer);
console.log(customer)
```

which gets me the email, but the name is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Customers created through Checkout have a `null` name because it is not collected/set. The "name on card" field on the Checkout page is for the cardholder name for the payment method, not the name of the customer (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details-name). If you want a Customer created through Checkout to not have a `null` name, you'll have to update the Customer after the session is completed.

Stripe has a dashboard setting (https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails) you can enable that automatically sends receipts to customers for successful payments completed in live mode. Payments completed in test mode will not automatically send an email, but you can trigger one manually through the dashboard. You can read more about sending receipts here: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#automatically-send-receipts-when-payments-are-successful.

If you want to grab the customer’s email and send a receipt yourself it’ll be a bit more complicated.

1. Wait for the Checkout Session to finish by listening for `checkout_session.completed` through a webhook endpoint (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#handle-the-checkoutsessioncompleted-event).
2. Grab the customer ID from the Checkout Session object that comes in with the `checkout_session.completed` event.
3. Using the customer ID from the previous step, retrieve the Customer object (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) and get the customer’s email.

Comment: I would also need the name from the checkout session.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Name should also be returned from step 3 (when you retrieve the Customer object). https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-name

Comment: I am facing the same problem, the customer name is null after retrieving the customer.